# Does PHP support proper time comparisons if-statement?

Tags: php, function, datetime, if-statement, comparison

I want to check whether it is working times using PHP. But I wasn't able to do a proper time comparison using any of the date functions. Does PHP support time comparisons with the use of date functions or not?

Currently I solved my issue by calculating the amount of the minutes of the day have passed:

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');
    $hours = date('G');
    $minutes = date('i');
    $totalMinutes = ($hours * 60) + $minutes;
    $betweenMinutes1 = (8 * 60) + 30;
    $betweenMinutes2 = (17 * 60) + 0;

    echo $hours.' * 60 + '.$minutes.' = '.$totalMinutes.' minuten van de 1440 op een dag verstreken <br/><br/>';

    echo 'if '.$totalMinutes.' is between '.$betweenMinutes1.' and '.$betweenMinutes2.' it is workingtime:';

    if (!($totalMinutes > $betweenMinutes1 && $totalMinutes < $betweenMinutes2)) {
        echo 'It isn\'t workingtime.';
    } else {
        echo 'It is workingtime.';
    }
?>
```

**Is this this the best way, or is there a way to do this using the proper date functions within the if-statement**

Comment: If you use DateTime objects, then 100% yes, otherwise (using the standard date functions) you have to convert to unix timestamps to compare.... but times are never purely times, they're always dates and times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow that's pretty long code for a very small condition; You just want to check if current time is in your given range

```
$current=date("Gi");   // hours without leading zeroes and minutes with.
if($current > 830 && $current < 1700)   // 0830 to 1700 hours
{
    // we're open 
}
```

To answer your actual question, yes PHP does have time comparison functions. You can find a bunch of them **[here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php)**